# How to plot function of three or more variable?

Tags: integration

How to plot function of two or more variable ? Also,why do we require perpendicular axis for the function to be examined ?

Answer (score 0):

We don't necessarily require a perpendicular axis for examining a function.  It just provides us the easiest way to inspect a continuous function.

You could imagine inspecting $y=f(x)$ along a single dimension number line, where the darkness of color of the line is determined by the function.

A function of two variables could be plotted as a 3D contour.  A function of 3 variables could be examined in a 3D space, where the function is represented, say, by the size of a sphere.  Although you could only examine sampled values, not continuously.